# File path different in webapp deploy

Tags: c#, azure, .net-5

We have a database migration set of code we run with the custom config on the classes being:

```
builder.HasData(SeedDataHelper.SeedFromJson<Make>("../Project/Seeds/Makes.json"));
```

And this works fine doing a local migration.

The problem is that when we deploy the app, the new file path for seeds is:

```
../wwwroot/Seeds/Makes.json
```

Is there a way to either keep the path the same after a deploy, or have a setting to determine which path to use?

I have tried adding a local.settings.json and telling startup to read the json into environmental variables. But when using GetEnvironmentalVariable. I get null returned.

Comment: Wouldn't 
`builder.HasData(SeedDataHelper.SeedFromJson<Make>("Seeds/Makes.json"));` suffice? You are going one folder up to access the folder when you are already in the folder?

Comment: @pevecg So we have a project called persistence where the config code is. But SeedFromJson is in a different helper project. If I use "Makes.json" for example it tries and looks for the file in: \ApiProject\Makes.json'. But the local seeds are in \PersistenceProject\Makes.json'.

Comment: Instead of "../Project/Seeds/Makes.json" try "~/Project/Seeds/Makes.json" once and check.

Answer (score 0):

The solution should be more environment independent if you keep that path in the application configuration set during deployment. that way you will be flexible to have that from different locations depending on the environment your application is running.

1. Local Environment: you can use the appsettings.json to store that directory:

```
    {
          applicationPaths: {
              seeds:"PATH HERE"
          }
      }
```

2. Configure the startup that you want to access your configuration entries as environment variables entries. you can setup in the startup the configurationBuilder with AddEnvironmentVariables() method call

```
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                             .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)                             
                             .AddEnvironmentVariables(); // override settings with environment variables
    
             
    
        }
```

now you will have this configuration available to be read from the Environment Variable as applicationPaths:seeds but from the application code it is just a configuration entry.

3. Configure your webapp.

You need to configure the entry as "applicationPaths.seeds" during deployment of your webapp like this:
[image]